# Axum with Leptos: how do I get AppState in [server] Macro?

Tags: rust, rust-axum, leptos

I try to work with axum and leptos on a fullstack app

I am trying to use a server shared resource with SSR leptos handlers, which usually would be an AppState struct added to the router with `with_state()`

After studying multiple examples, I am wondering: how do I deal with the AppState, that I usually load with "State" in an axum handler, when I use a leptos #[server]-Macro based handler function?

```rust
#[server(Something, "/api")]
pub async fn something(cx: Scope, arg: MyStruct, state: State<AppState>) -> Result<String, ServerFnError> { ... }
```

will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking further I finally managed to make it work, the hint was in the docs, which lead me to this piece of code:

[Example of using custom routes](https://github.com/leptos-rs/leptos/blob/a5f73b441c079f9138102b3a7d8d4828f045448c/examples/session_auth_axum/src/main.rs#L91-L92)

In essence,

1. define a custom route-handler for `leptos_routes_with_handler` which calls `leptos_axum::render_app_to_stream_with_context` and provides required states  there in the context
2. define a server_fn_handler that calls `handle_server_fn_with_context`, yet again providing the states yet again in the context
3. define some kind of extractor function that you can use from your `#[server]` function, that uses `use_context::T` to extract the type from the Scope.

I personally used the approach to define a function on a state I want to extract:

```
impl MyState {
    pub fn from_cx(cx: Scope) -> Result<MyState, ServerFnError> {
                use_context::<MyState>(cx)
                    .ok_or_else(|| ServerFnError::ServerError("My State missing.".into()))
    }
}
```

so I can retrieve it inside my

```rust
#[server(Something, "/api")]
pub async fn something(cx: Scope, arg: MyStruct) -> Result<String, ServerFnError> {
   let my_state = MyState::from_cx(cx)?;
}
```

but the example code in the repo uses a simple function (see in todo.rs), and uses two substates of the AppState, the AuthSession and the SqlitePool, that are delivered via Scope.